# Sqlite3 database empty after running migration in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

this is db.js

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const path = require('path')
const { migrationScript } = require('../db/migrations/migrate');
const WDIR = process.cwd();
const DB_PATH = path.join(WDIR, 'db', 'DB.db');

const db = new sqlite3.Database(DB_PATH, (err) => {if (err) { console.log(err);}});
db.run(migrationScript, (err) => {if (err) { console.log(err);}})
db.close()
```

migrate.js doesn't even matter as it's just a const multiline string  and it gets ignored

no matter what i type in it. i also get no erros.
after execution it creates a 0kb file that ofcourse doesn't have any tables or nothing.
im mentioning that migrationscript starts with pragma foreign_keys = on, but again it doens't seem to even read it. i tried using serialize and doing the db.run inside it, didn't matter.
yes i checked, migrationScript object is NOT empty inside db.js. it seems fine

Comment: How can the contents of `migrate.js` not matter? That's where the code to perform the migration should be.

Comment: Do you see the expected value if you do `console.log(migrationScript)`?

Comment: I think you need to use `db.exec()` to execute multiple statements, not `db.run()`.

Comment: Bramar has the right answer. i needed to use db.exec().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `db.exec()` rather than `db.run()` to execute a string containing multiple queries.

```
db.exec(migrationScript, (err) => {if (err) { console.log(err);}})
```